# Implementing conditional variables with System V semaphores

Tags: c, linux, ipc, semaphore

I am trying to implement conditional variable using System V semaphores. For simplicity let's assume that only one process may wait on a conditional variable at a time. The concept seems simple so just take a look at my implementation of mutex and conditional variable wrappers where:

- Mutex is a binary semaphore with 1 standing for free and 0 for locked.
- Conditional variable is a binary semaphore with 1 meaning that someone is waiting on it and 0 otherwise.

Here it goes:

```
//Sets value of 'num' semaphore from 'semid' semaphore set to be 'val'.
// Returns 0 on success and -1 on failure.
int set_value(int semid, int num, int val)
{
    union semun setval_semun;
    setval_semun.val = val;
    return semctl(semid, num, SETVAL, setval_semun);
}

// Returns the value of semaphore 'num' from 'semid' semaphore set
// or -1 on failure.
int get_value(int semid, int num)
{
    return semctl(semid, num, GETVAL);
}

// Locks 'mutex'. Returns 0 on success and 1 if 'mutex' is invalid.
// Returns -1 on other error.
int lock_mutex(int semid, int mutex)
{
    struct sembuf op;

    if (get_value(semid, mutex) > 1) return 1;

    op.sem_num  = mutex;
    op.sem_op   = -1;
    op.sem_flg  = 0;

    return semop(semid, &op, 1);
}

// Unlocks 'mutex'. Returns 0 on success and 1 ig the 'mutex' isn't locked.
// Returns -1 on different error.
int unlock_mutex(int semid, int mutex)
{
    struct sembuf op;

    if (get_value(semid, mutex) != 0) return 1;

    op.sem_num  = mutex;
    op.sem_op   = 1;
    op.sem_flg  = 0;

    return semop(semid, &op, 1);
}

// Waits on condition 'cond' and frees 'mutex'.
// Returns 0 on success and 1 if either some other process is waiting on 'cond'
// or 'mutex' is not locked. Returns -1 on other failure.
int wait_cond(int semid, int cond, int mutex)
{
    struct sembuf   ops[2];

    if (get_value(semid, cond) != 0 || get_value(semid, mutex) != 0)
        return 1;

    ops[0].sem_num  = cond;
    ops[0].sem_op   = 1;
    ops[0].sem_flg  = 0;

    semop(semid, ops, 1);

    ops[0].sem_num  = mutex;
    ops[0].sem_op   = 1;
    ops[0].sem_flg  = 0;

    ops[1].sem_num  = cond;
    ops[1].sem_op   = 0;
    ops[1].sem_flg  = 0;

    return semop(semid, ops, 2);
}

// Wakes up process waiting for 'cond'. Returns 0 on success. Returns 1 when
// no process is waiting for 'cond' and -1 on other error.
int wake_cond(int semid, int cond)
{
    struct sembuf   op;

    if (semctl(semid, cond, GETVAL) != 1)
        return 1;

    op.sem_num  = cond;
    op.sem_op   = -1;
    op.sem_flg  = 0;

    return semop(semid, &op, 1);
}
```

Now check out my minimal test program. It consists of two processes sharing two semaphores. One is serving as a mutex, and the other one as a conditional variable. They both have the same flow:

1. Lock mutex.
2. Do something.
3. Wake up process waiting for conditional variable.
4. Wait for conditional variable using mutex.

If I get this whole stuff right, they should be doing 'something' alternately.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    key_t       key     = 0;
    pid_t       pid     = 0;
    int         semid   = 0;
    int const   mutex   = 0;
    int const   cond    = 1;
    int         repeat  = 5;
    char const* name    = NULL;
    union semun setval_semun;

    // Create unique key.
    key = get_unique_key(argv[0], 47); 
    if (key == -1)
        return 1;

    // Create and intialize semaphore set.
    semid = semget(key, 2, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if (semid == -1)
        return 1;
    if (set_value(semid, mutex, 1) != 0 || set_value(semid, cond, 1) != 0)
    {
        semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID);
        return 1;
    }

    // Fork.
    pid = fork();
    if (fork() < 0)
        return 1;
    else if(pid > 0)
        name = "parent";
    else
        name = " child";

    while(repeat--)
    {
        printf("%s: (0), mutex: %d, cond: %d, repeat: %d\n", name,
            get_value(semid, mutex), get_value(semid, cond), repeat);

        if (lock_mutex(semid, mutex) != 0) return 1;

        sleep(1);

        printf("%s: (1), mutex: %d, cond: %d, repeat: %d\n", name,
            get_value(semid, mutex), get_value(semid, cond), repeat);

        if (wake_cond(semid, cond) != 0) return 1;

        printf("%s: (2), mutex: %d, cond: %d, repeat: %d\n", name,
            get_value(semid, mutex), get_value(semid, cond), repeat);

        if (repeat == 0)
        {
            if (unlock_mutex(semid, mutex) != 0) return 1;
        }
        else if (wait_cond(semid, cond, mutex) != 0) return 1;

        printf("%s: (3), mutex: %d, cond: %d, repeat: %d\n", name,
            get_value(semid, mutex), get_value(semid, cond), repeat);
    }

    //Wait for child and clear resources.
    if (pid > 0)
    {
        wait(NULL);
        semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output i get which is insanely bizarre:

```
parent: (0), mutex: 1, cond: 1, repeat: 4 
parent: (0), mutex: 0, cond: 1, repeat: 4
 child: (0), mutex: 0, cond: 1, repeat: 4
 child: (0), mutex: 0, cond: 1, repeat: 4
parent: (1), mutex: 0, cond: 1, repeat: 4
parent: (2), mutex: 0, cond: 0, repeat: 4
^C
```

Especially look at the first two lines. They tell you that the notice number (0) was printed twice in the same run of the while loop with different values! Of cource it ends up in a deadlock so I ^C it.

Dont bother about the get_unique_key() function - it does just what it's name says.

Any help in making this work or explaining the strange output will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have two **fork** calls?

Comment: I guess this is an error and it destroys everything... Thanks. Too bad this was sooo long ago.